# Firebase Cloud Function cannot write storage

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I tried to make a cloud function that write a file in Firebase Storage everytime I add new document in a collection in firestore

my dummy code is quite simple:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');


exports.writeToStorage = functions.firestore.document("problems/{problem_id}").onCreate(
    (snap, context) => {
        admin.initializeApp();
        var storage = admin.storage();
        var fileStream = storage.bucket("test").file("test.txt").createWriteStream();
        fileStream.write("Hello, World!");
        fileStream.on('error', (err) => {
            console.error(`${ this.archive }: Error storage file write.`);
            console.error(`${ this.archive }: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
        });
        fileStream.end();
    }
);
```

but somehow I cannot make it work, this is the error I get from the log:

> {"code":403,"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"forbidden","message":"xxx-dev-exxxe@appspot.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.create access to test/test.txt."}],"message":"xxx-dev-exxxe@appspot.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.create access to test/test.txt."}

I tried to set the IAM role on google cloud console and give that account and default firebase-admin-sdk account 'Storage Admin' role but I still get the same error

Comment: First, try putting `admin.initializeApp();` into global space, under the `require`? [Here is some documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start) on using admin with storage buckets.

Comment: @JamesPoag There's no requirement to put the init in global space.  How it's written right now is OK.  What I find suspect here is the lack of use of any promises to indicate to Cloud Functions when the async work is complete.